The energy-momentum tensor is symmetric, why we have different interpretation of $T^{i0}$ and $T^{0i}$?
A very subtle thing is in Wiki I found the energy-momentum tensor in GR is automatically symmetric.
So whether the relativistic energy-momentum tensor is always symmetric? Whether this implies some relativistic constrain?
So whether this is just some coincidence?

Note that the questions you're asking in the title vs. in the post itself are somewhat different (though clearly related). It is better if you can edit and focus on one question only

@Amit You're right, but I think these questions are highly coupled. I guess if I can understand one of them completely, I will understand other.
Another point is I just cant post the question if the description of the problem is thought to be "low quality"

The two questions are highly coupled I agree, which is why I also think for practical purposes can be put in one question. I only meant that you may want to reiterate the question in the title, also in the body of the post. That way people answering will actually address both aspects of the question, if one of them remains only in the title, it may be overlooked

It's worth going through the argument for the symmetry of the non-relativistic stress-tensor, if you haven't already. It boils down to the fact that if you carefully follow the implications of having different fluxes of appropriate momentum components in different directions, it would imply particles moving with an infinite acceleration. See, eg, Tong's fluid mechanics lectures, Section 3.1.

Possible duplicate: Why is the stress-energy tensor symmetric? More on symmetry of SEM tensor.

$T^{i0}$ energy flux , $T^{0i}$ momentum density. The Symmetry follows from the fact that energy and momentum are the same thing rewieved  in different reference frames. If energy is flowing in the system , we must have momentum as well. Energy flux is thus equivalent to momentum density. This tensor is symmetric in general theory of relativity.
